# How to evaluate user policy via API for a given set of users

Tags: java, api, oim

I want to evaluate user policies for a particular user or list of users, is there any API available to perform the same in OIM 11gR2PS3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `oracle.iam.accesspolicy.api.AccessPolicyService.evalutePoliciesForUser()` OIM API which can be used for the same. Here is the code snippet for the same.